# Calling C++ code in a DLL from C# to get a string back

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I'm using a C++ DLL from C# . Everything works ok apart from a function that takes in input a string pointer and fill it with data. I have the source code of the DLL, and the aforementioned function's code is this:

```
int CDLL::GetCode(char *CodeN)
{
    int year, cn, sn1;

    year = m_dwCode >> 24;
    year += 2000;
    sn = (m_dwCode >> 8) & (0xFFFF);
    sn1 = m_dwCode & (0xFF);

    if (sn1 != 0) {
        sprintf(CodeN, "%d-%d-%d", year, cn, sn1);
    }
    else {
        sprintf(CodeN, "%d-%d", year, sn);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The function itself is exported with this:

```
_declspec(dllexport) int WINAPI  GetCode(char *sn)
{
    return ((CDLL*)AfxGetApp())->GetCode(sn);
};
```

I've tried to import it in a number of different ways, but none seems to work; I always get back garbage instead of the expected code.

This is the last import I've tried:

```
[DllImport("CDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
internal extern static int GetCode([param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr), Out()] StringBuilder sn);
```

And this is the calling code:

```
StringBuilder myCode = new StringBuilder("xxxx-yyyyy-zzz");
Wrapper.GetCode(myCode);
return myCode.ToString();
```

But I **always** end up with garbage into the string, and a string longer than what I expect.

---

Note, before someone ask it: the DLL is working ok, have been used for years in a VB.Net software, and I'm testing/developing in a fully working environment.

Just for completeness, the VB code declares it as
    (ByVal sc As String)
and calls the function with

```
Dim tempCode As String
tempCode = "xxxx-yyyyy-zzz";
GetCode(tempCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

for use with c#, I typically export my c++ functions with C names. 
Since you used c++ names I suggest trying to dllimport by the ordinal number rather than the function name.
something like

```
[DllImport("CDLL.dll", EntryPoint="#25")]
```

Ive also noticed that your function names dont match in your dllimport. 
In your C++ you call it "GetCode" but in dllimport youve called it "UTB_GetCode"
 You can change the names for sure if you want to, but you will need to define the entry point in your dll import statement

Comment: Yeah, the UTB part was an error while rewriting things here